# Cannot add Object.assign to google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I added something like this to an utils.gs file in google sheets:

```
Object.assign = function (target, source){
  if (!target || !source)
    throw new Error("Invalid arguments.");
  for (var property in source)
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(property))
      target[property] = source[property];
};
```

In the same script file I defined a function which depends on `Object.assign`, but I always got an error message:

> TypeError: Cannot find function assign in object function Object() {
>   [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }.

Any idea why I cannot add it?

Comment: I think that that polyfill can be used. So I think that you might have not correctly called ``Object.assign()`` and/or it might be put out of the scope. For example, how about putting it as a global variable? If that is not the direct solution, can you provide the sample script for replicating your situation? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize. As an additional information, when I call the function while the function is put out of the scope, I could confirm the same error occurs, just now.

Comment: @Tanaike Nope, I cannot add any property to a function and it can find only functions in global namespace. I guess it is caused by a shitty written interpreter or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for replying. As other workaround, for example, how about using by declaring as ``assign = function(target, source){}``?

Comment: @Tanaike It's even weirder than I expected. If I use `Object.assign = utilsAssign;` in the utils.gs, then I can use it in the main.gs, but I guess only if there are other dependencies too. So it needs to find function dependency to import the file I guess. Instead of using a decent module system, it uses some sort of half implemented auto load or who knows what. Does not really matter, I managed to write what I needed.

Comment: I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some sort of bug in the module system.

This code works:

**main.gs**

```
Object.assign = function (target, source){
  if (!target || !source)
    throw new Error("Invalid arguments.");
  for (var property in source)
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(property))
      target[property] = source[property];
  return target;
};

Logger.log(Object.assign({}, {a:1}));

function main(){
  Logger.log(Object.assign({}, {a:1}));
}
```

But if I move the `Object.assign` to a separate file:

**main.gs**

```
Logger.log(Object.assign({}, {a:1}));

function main(){
  Logger.log(Object.assign({}, {a:1}));
}
```

**assign.gs**

```
Object.assign = function (target, source){
  if (!target || !source)
    throw new Error("Invalid arguments.");
  for (var property in source)
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(property))
      target[property] = source[property];
  return target;
};
```

then only the second `Object.assign()` works, which is called in the `main()` function. If I define and call `assign()` instead, then both works.

Note that this is normally not a problem, because you usually don't add both lines to the `main.gs`. If you use utility functions to help prototype creation, then it is better to move every constructor and prototype definition to a separate file instead of defining them in the `main.gs`. That way you won't have such problems and you can use `Object.assign` even in your other utility functions and definitions.